# Pass unordered List selected item to ASP.NET Web Forms using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I asked a question earlier but didn't phrase it correctly.

I am working with jQuery and Bootstrap for pretty much the first time and need some help.

I have an `.aspx` webpage that has this code:

```
<form method="POST" action="Search.aspx">
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="srchterm" id="srchterm" style="width: 300px" />
        <button id="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            GO!</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a id="reportType" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"
                 name="rptType">Select report type<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li id="1"><a href="#">All</a></li>
                <li id="2"><a href="#">Some</a></li>
                <li id="3"><a href="#">None</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a id="reportStatus" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                Report Status<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li id="1"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                <li id="2"><a href="#">Archived</a></li>
                <li id="3"><a href="#">All</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

What I would like to know is how I can pass the value of the selected unordered list item to the code behind using JQuery or AJAX. Neither method I know much (or to be totally honest) anything about.

When I hit the submit button it takes the text box value and passes that back to `Request.Form("srchTerm")` but i cant seem to get anything else to pass.

I have seen this link here at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RyG95/1/) but cant seem to get it to work for me.

I am wondering if its because how I have declared my listbox, but do need help in order to get this to work.

If I am missing a tag, please let me know. But I would very much appreciate the help with the JavaScript to get this wired up to pass the data so I can call the information from my database.

====================================

## edit 1

I've tried various methods, none of which i have kept, but this is that i have right now and cant get anything to pass a value across.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText + '     <span class="caret"></span>');
});

$('.reportType li').click(function () {
    value1 = $(this).attr('value');
});

$('.reportStatus li').click(function () {
    value2 = $(this).attr('value');
});

$('#Submit').click(function () {
    alert('value1 = ' + value1 + ' | value2 = ' + value2);
});
```

Comment: post your jquery code and the rest of your code

Comment: I have edited the code to show what I have right now, which isnt much.

Comment: But if you could help me with passing the code from the form, to the code behind that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: So, what you want is a way to pass to `search.aspx` the `li` that the user has selected? This code is not from `search.aspx` but from another page, right?

Comment: you should use radio buttons to select not list items, or at least checkboxes

Comment: The html is on the search page, I would like either have a post back or Ajax to then make the call and then there will be a data grid on the page with the results.

Comment: But if like to know and understand how to donit

Comment: The end user wants a drop down, would it be possible to mask radio buttons in this way?

Comment: Ok, so i have the radion buttons, how can I convert these to a drop down list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must have dropdown list and you want to maintain this type of functionality, then i'd simply use hidden input fields something like this:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
   <input type="hidden" id="reportStatus" name="reportStatus" />
   <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select" 
      data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
        Report Status
        <span class="caret"></span>
   </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li data-val="1"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
     <li data-val="2"><a href="#">Archived</a></li>
     <li data-val="3"><a href="#">All</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

JS will be something like:

```
//$(function () {
//   $("#reportStatus").parents("div").find("li").click(function () {
//        value = $(this).attr("data-val");
//        $("#reportStatus").val(value);
//    })
//});

//or something more general:

$(function () {

    $(".btn-group").each(function (index, item) {
        myInput = $(item).children("input");

        $(item).find("li").click(function () {
            value = $(this).attr("data-val");
            myInput.val(value);

        });
    });
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g10Lus6o/)